# Firestore Snapshot Listener doesn't make a call and returns empty list

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I've been told adding a snapshot listener instead of doing an get() and await() will retrieve the database values just as easily, but so far it's done nothing.

The code that works:

```
override suspend fun getAllAppointments(): List<UserAppointment> {
        val userAppointments = ArrayList<UserAppointment>()
        appointmentRef.get().await().let {
            for (document in it) {
                userAppointments.add(document.toObject(UserAppointment::class.java))
            }
        }
        return userAppointments.toList()
    }
```

The code that doesn't work:

```
override fun subscribeToUpdates(): List<UserAppointment> {
        val userAppointments = ArrayList<UserAppointment>()
        appointmentRef.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error ->
            error.let {
                Timber.e(it)
            }
            querySnapshot?.let {
                for (document in it) {
                    userAppointments.add(document.toObject(UserAppointment::class.java))
                }
            }
        }
        return userAppointments.toList()
    }
```

All I need is to fetch a list of database items, but the latter returns nothing at all.

Comment: Loading data from Firestore (and most modern cloud APIs) is an asynchronous operation. In your code the `return userAppointments.toList()` runs before the `userAppointments.add(...)` every gets called. You can set breakpoints on those lines and run in a debugger to see that. --- See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o for a longer explanation

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't really understand. I get the return happens before everything else, but how do I fix it here? None of the examples in the link provided relate to a snapshot listener and I'm already shaky on firebase, as is.

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).